# Proving a Boolean expression.

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

How to prove that $(A \vee B) + (A \wedge B) \equiv A + B$?

Here $\vee$ and $\wedge$ are bitwise OR and bitwise AND operators, respectively. "$+$" is the arithmetic operator.

Example :- $(5 \vee 6) + (5 \wedge 6) \equiv 5 + 6 = 11$.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the 5 OR 6 = 5? I guess it is  7. 

Are you sure that 5 AND 6 = 6? I guess it is 4.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco by (5+6) I mean the RHS which is A + B.  LHS = 7+4 and RHS = 5+6 which is same.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: first check that it's true for $A = B = 2^n$ and for $A = 2^n$, $B = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can use structural induction.

First show that it holds for the base case $A = B = 0$.

Then show that if it holds for $(A, B)$ with $A_k = 0$, then it holds for $(A + 2^k, B)$.

Case 1, $B_k = 0$ :
$$( (A + 2^k) \lor B) + ((A + 2^k) \land B) = ((A \lor B) + 2^k) + (A \land B)$$

Case 2, $B_k = 1$ :
$$( (A + 2^k) \lor B) + ((A + 2^k) \land B) = (A \lor B) + ((A \land B) + 2^k)$$